# Brief syntax for inserting row into sqlite database using python sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, csv, sqlite

I have a csv file of size 360x120 that I want to import into my sqlite database row by row. For one row, I know that below syntax works if `mytuple` has 2 elements:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(dbLoc)
cur = conn.cursor()
mytuple = (a, b, c, ...) #some long tuple of 120 elements
cur.execute('INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (?, ?)', mytuple)
```

Problem is, my rows contain 120 columns and I can't really go type 120 question marks into the `cur.execute()` line. Actually I have, it works but yeah, it is not a good solution. One thing I have tried was:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ?', mytuple)
```

Thought it would just do `?=mytuple` and replace `?` with `mytuple` but it doesn't do that. A user comment on the article `sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_sqlite_in_python_tutorial.html` shows such syntax, which would work for me but it does not:

```
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
```

As seen here he's able to replace a tuple into the execute string with a single `?` used. How can I achieve the same with `INSERT INTO tablename`?

Comment: You could construct the 120 question marks with something like `','.join(itertools.repeat('?',120))`.

Comment: That's true, and as I said, I have done something like that and actually put 120 question marks there. But I still wanna know if there's a pretty and simple syntax something like I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Neither the PEP 0249 not the SQLite docs show any.

Comment: I searched the docs and the web all day yesterday and didn't see anything either. For now, I'm going with `'('+','.join(itertools.repeat('?',120))+')'` but it would be very nice that this ugly little piece could be replaced with a single `?`. Marked your comment as useful.

Comment: @KlausD.: to construct 120 question marks: `'?'*120`. Complete expression: `'({}?)'.format('?, '*119)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You might run both code snippets yourself and see the difference in output. ;-) Edit after your edit: Readability counts.

Comment: @KlausD.: I've provided the complete expression to show that you don't need `itertools.repeat()` here.

Comment: @KlausD.: If I thought that more verbose code is more readable; I would use Java instead of Python.

Comment: Good thing about `.format()` here instead of `.repeat()` is, 1. one less import (itertools) and 2. I don't even need `len(t)` because it is always a constant. I'll just say `'?, '*119` so it's cool. `VALUES ?` would be the best but yeah, we can't have it with sqlite apparently. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlite3` doesn't support more concise syntax:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ({}?)'.format('?,'*(len(t) - 1)), t)
```

Note: the default `SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN` is `2000`. And some algorithms in SQLite are `O(n**2)` in the number of columns i.e., if you increase the limit; it may slow down db operations.

Comment: Can't believe how I couldn't think of `'?, '*119`...This is better than my `'('+blahblah+')'` syntax. Thank you.